# jQuery Back Button - transaction hidden page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I’ve build a small single file jQuery Mobile page/site. 
My site has following flow: 
`HomePage -> DataPage -> EditData`

**I have a problem with back button.**

I’ve tried to use `<a href="#HomePage " data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="reverse slide">Back</a>` with `href` pointing to `HomePage`

All works fine here **except the transitions look like it is scrolling through empty page in the middle**. Once I remove the **reverse** all works fine, but the animation is in the wrong direction according to my flow at the top.

**[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/yKwmL/)**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you clarify what is wrong with the fiddle you posted? what do you want to improve on it?

Comment: When you click `back` on `DataPage` it is doing a scroll, and effect looks like it is scrolling two pages, not one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `data-direction` please check the example from jQM site.

```
<a href="docs-transitions.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-active ui-btn-up-b" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">
```

You can also check the other examples from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html)

Comment: This works as long I as do not use the save button.  Once I use the save button to change the page the flow is destroyed and on the `back event` from `DataPage` it is going back to `EditData`

Comment: And where is save button supposed to go?

Comment: Well, it is another issue you but what what are you doing with the save button do you add extra content or page? I think you are using an AJAX request and create new page(div with role=page). if this is the case create the page in the first place and load it is content it should work. If not or this is not the case what is happening and what do you want to see? Shortly more details.

Comment: Please go here: http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/yKwmL/ Look at the JS, it has two click events, for `edit & save` This is how I create save,edit transition/flow. This is shorter version, without AJAX used to save the data (custom).

Comment: Another interesting fact is that, when you hover over back button it is showing URL as `http://someurl/#HomePage`, but it is taking you to `http://someurl/#EditData`

Comment: @Gajotres - it should go to HomePage, as the href indicates `href="#HomePage"`

Comment: I will write a solution as an answer, just so you can see it with formatted.

Comment: @Gajotres- got it! `href="#Homepage"` is being overridden  by `data-rel="back"`  Once remove the `data-rel="back"` the `href` works fine!

Comment: Sry I was late with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part of code from your back button:

```
data-rel="back"
```

Because of it it acts as a real back button, and it led you to last page which was SaveDate.