# How to remove white screen between page navigation android with phonegap

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new in phonegap in `Android`. I have done my application with phonegap and `jQuery Mobile`, my problem is that when navigate one page to another page between this white screen displayed, not displayed loader.

I want on page navigation first java script first loaded and how to remove white screen between page navigation.

Comment: Please show us an short example, mainly buttons/header buttons used for page transition. It is usually problem do to wrong transition settings.

Comment: I am using $.mobile.changePage with transition slide

Comment: I need more info, we had a similar question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581292/jquery-back-button-transaction-hidden-page Maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 2):

First setup your jQuery option to this :  $.defaultPageTransition:'none' , then you should set up the links in your nav bar as per the below:

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-theme="a"  data-grid="c">
<ul data-transition="none" >
<li><a data-transition="none" href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" id="Page1"  data-icon="custom">Page1</a></li>
<li><a data-transition="none"  href="#Page2"   id="Page2" data-icon="custom">Page2</a></li>
<li><a data-transition="none"  href="#Page3"   id="Page3" data-icon="custom">Page3</a></li>
<li><a data-transition="none"  href="#Page4"   id="Page4" data-icon="custom">Page4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

alternatively you may use the changepage method as per the below:

```
        $.mobile.changePage("#pageid", {
            transition: "none",
            reverse: true,
            changeHash: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are correctly ajax loading the pages, you're probably running into a bug/feature in jquery mobile introduced because some devices had trouble with better transitions. Fortunately there is a simple fix for that available.

https://github.com/watusi/jquery.mobile.simultaneous-transitions

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
$.mobile.changePage('#yourPage', "slide");
```

???

If doesn't resolved, see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html

Answer (score 0):

Use phonegap latest. Use corodova-2.2.0.
Also it should be  $.defaultPageTransition:'none'

Answer (score 0):

Change the script section from `HEAD` tag to `BODY` tag